# How to delete a connector plugin in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Here's the list of my connector plugins:

```
> curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins
{
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.tools.SchemaSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1.1.0-cp1"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "4.1.0"
}, {
    "class": "io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1.1.0-cp1"
}, {
    "class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "0.7.5"
}, {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
    "type": "sink",
    "version": "1.1.0-cp1"
}, {
    "class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "1.1.0-cp1"
}
```

How can I delete the following connector?

```
{
    "class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "type": "source",
    "version": "0.7.5"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove it from your `plugin.path`.

Answer (score 0):

`plugin.path` is path at which all connector files gets installed. for example it could be `/opt/confluent-7.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components/`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31147517)